# How do I use multiple integers in an equation (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, binary

I coded a conversion tool from binary to integer, but it had a limit on how large the number can be. So, I tried to code a formula for binary. I came up with an equation, so I tried to put it into code. Everything worked, except for applying the equation to each digit. This is the equation I came up with:

Let `d` represent the integer
Let `z` represent any (and every) digit

```
d = z[2^(z-1)]
```

This is what I've coded so far:

```
answer = gets.chomp
n = answer.reverse # reverses the answer
y1 = answer.size # the amount of digits in the answer
x1 = answer
z = (1..y1).each { |z| puts z } # every number between 1 and number of digits
w = (1..1).each.to_a * y1.to_i #in case I need to multiply the entire array
s = x1 # [z] - 1 # any given digit minus one
v = 2 ** s.to_i # exponent
u = z.zip(w).map{|x, y| x * y} # an array: [1, 2, 3]
print u
t = u.to_i # Tried converting to integer
puts x1[t]
```

But when I ran that, for example, with the number 1011, I got this error:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
undefined method `to_i' for [1, 2, 3, 4]:Array
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_a
               to_h
(repl):16:in `<main>'
```

I feel like I have tried everything, but if you somehow find a way to apply the equation to every digit, or if you come up with a simpler equation, please tell me.

Comment: Well I am not sure what you are going for since `1011` should be `11` however I do have a simpler solution `answer = gets.chomp.to_i(2)`. `String#to_i` takes an argument of `base` and `binary` is base 2 so `"1011".to_i(2) #=> 11`

Comment: guessing, but looks like `u` is an Array so you can't call `to_i` on it only the elements within it, e.g. `u.map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: thank you engineersmnky that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This return an array `u = z.zip(w).map{|x, y| x * y}` so you are triying to conver an array to integer. If you want, you can do something like this:

```
array = [1,0,1]     #your binary in array form
s = array.join('')  #transform it into string
s.to_i(2)           #this return the integer and result (2) represents base
```

[Check this link](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i)

And for better: `array.join('').to_i(2)`